# How can Joda or Java returns true if day is the first day of the month?

Tags: java, date, boolean, jodatime

How in Joda or Java can I write a method that **returns a boolean value** if today is the **first day of the current month**? Like if today's date is the first day of this month, it will return `true`.

It could be something like this:

```
public static boolean isFirstDayOfTheMonth( Date dateToday ){
boolean isFirstDay = false;
//code to check if dateToday is first day of the current month.
returns isFirstDay;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried to fill in the `//code to check if dateToday is first day of the month.` part?

Comment: I won't type an entire example but I can tell you that "Calendar" is the way to go.

Comment: First day of month in which time zone? It's always 5 o'clock somewhere...

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `LocalDate::getDayOfMonth`

With Java SE 8 and later, call [`LocalDate::getDayOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfMonth--).

```
public static boolean isFirstDayOfTheMonth(LocalDate dateToday ){
  return dateToday.getDayOfMonth() == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Joda-time

```
public static boolean isFirstDayOfTheMonth( DateTime dateToday ){
returns dateToday.dayOfMonth().get()==1
}
```

Comment: Shorten to `dateToday.getDayOfMonth() == 1`.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

This code gives you the result you need.

```
public static boolean isFirstDayOfTheMonth(Date dateToday){
  Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
  c.setTime(dateToday );
  if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 1) {
    return true;
  }
  returns false;
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the default TimeZone (and to a lesser extent Locale) of the OS are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use this with a normal java Date:

```
public static boolean isFirstDayOfTheMonth( Date dateToday ){
     if(dateToday.getDate() == 1){
        System.out.println("First of the month");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false';
    }

}
```

I hope this helps. And good luck with the rest of your code.

Comment: `getDate()` is `@Deprecated` method

Comment: Is it? ok forgot about that lukily there are other good answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `Date` class, it has deprecated methods. Calendar is better.

```
public boolean isFirstDayOfMonth(Calendar calendar)
{
    return calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 1;
}
```

Example method call:

```
isFirstDayOfMonth(Calendar.getInstance());
```