# How to check if the current date is the first of the month

Tags: java, date, equality

I'm trying to write a function which involves checking if the current date is the first of the month such as  01/03/2015 for example and then run something depending if it is.

It doesn't matter whether it is a date or calendar object, I just want to check if the current date when the code is run is the first of the month

Comment: you mean if it is 1st day of the month?

Comment: @taimeili123 yes that's what I mean sorry it was badly worded

Comment: `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 1` ?

Comment: @NickKaraolis is the date format always gonna be `MM/DD/YYYY`?

Comment: @taimeili123 That's irrelevant: *"the current date"*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can Joda or Java returns true if day is the first day of the month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451419/how-can-joda-or-java-returns-true-if-day-is-the-first-day-of-the-month)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a getter for that:

```
public boolean isFirstDayofMonth(Calendar calendar){
    if (calendar == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Calendar cannot be null.");
    }

    int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return dayOfMonth == 1;
}
```

Comment: An exception or an `Optional` is ways better than returning `false`on `null`

Comment: @OlegSkylar That is context dependent, but I agree. I will update.

Answer (score 6):

**Java 8 solution with LocalDate and TemporalAdjuster**

first day of month:

```
someDate.isEqual(someDate.with(firstDayOfMonth()))
```

last day of month:

```
someDate.isEqual(someDate.with(lastDayOfMonth())
```

This solution uses [TemporalAdjusters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) utility from `java.time.temporal`. It is common practice to use it as `import static` but you can also use it as `TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()`

Comment: Nice that someone at last (after three years) provided the `java.time` answer, the modern answer. Thanks. Still simpler: `someDate.getDayOfMonth() == 1`.

Comment: You should explain where `first/lastDayOfMonth()` comes from.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean isFirstDayOfTheMonth(Date dateToday){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(dateToday );

    if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 1) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Generally better to use  Calendar.getInstance() and let the JVM decide which Calendar to use rather than enforcing the use of GregorianCalendar